# MVC Bundling and Azure CDN caching issues

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, bundle, web-optimization, azure-cdn

In a current .NET webproject with ASP.NET MVC 5.2 and WebAPI 2.2, we encounter some strange troubles with minification and bundling in local/production environments.

For local development, we won't use bundling and minification, so we created a key/value pair in our web.config to switch between those settings.

**Deploy to Azure with Web Optimization v 1.1.3**

The browser won't cache the bundles locally in production because the `cache-control header` is automatically set to `no-cache`. This seems to be a known issue ([Cache-Control="no-cache" always in "Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization"](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/127) ) and their only suggestion is to downgrade to v1.1.1

After the downgrade to v1.1.1, most requests has the right value (`cache-control: public`), but some of them are still with `no-cache`, so I think the real issue isn't solved with downgrading.

**Local development with Web Optimization v 1.1.1**

When we turn off the CDN and minification option in our web settings, some files won't be loaded in our application.

Seems like the method `IncludeDirectory` doesn't work in v1.1.1 (according to an issue reported on codeplex, [IncludeDirectory doesn't add path to files when debugging in version 1.1.1](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/105)). Because some folders have a lot of files, it's a lot of work to manually add all these files.